# Quick way to convert CSV types to original types with PowerShell's Import-Csv cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using PowerShell v2 and have a custom type I've defined called Material using code like this:

```
add-type @"
public struct Material {
    public string BusinessUnit;
    public string Source;
    public string PrimarySource;
    public string LegacyMaterialNumber;
}
"@
```

...and I've got a collection of objects of this type I'm writing to a CSV file using the Export-Csv cmdlet. That works fine and produces data with the original type specified like this:

```
#TYPE Material          
BusinessUnit,Source,PrimarySource,LegacyMaterialNumber
BU1,NAFO,NAFO-FG,17502
BU1,NAFO,NAFO-FG,17504
BU1,NAFO,NAFO-FG,17739
BU1,NAFO,NAFO-FG,17837
BU1,NAFO,NAFO-FG,17841
```

The issue I'm running into is when I import this data back using *Import-Csv* each line is created as the type:

```
CSV:Material
```

...instead of the original type I started with:

```
Material
```

In my specific case this is an issue because I want to pass each Material into a function with a parameter specifically typed as *Material*. I could parse each row and rebuild my Material objects with the data of course, but is there a quick way to just import the CSV data as the original type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Import-Csv` wants to create a `PSObject` based type. You can create a conversion function (or filter) to convert to a Material type. Then pipe the output of `import-csv` to this function and into your target array:

```
filter convert-csvToMaterial([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]$csvMaterial)
{
    $material = new-object -TypeName Material 
    $material.BusinessUnit = $csvMaterial.BusinessUnit
    $material.LegacyMaterialNumber = $csvMaterial.LegacyMaterialNumber
    $material.PrimarySource = $csvMaterial.PrimarySource
    $material.Source = $csvMaterial.Source
    $material
}

$importedMaterial = import-csv .\materialList.csv | convert-csvToMaterial
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of using a filter in your last statement, but am still hopeful it's possible to avoid having to write the filter at all. If not, I'll gladly accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to dynamically create a hashtable from the custom objects returned by [`Import-Csv`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) and use them as the `-Property` argument to [`New-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113355):

```powershell
filter Convert-CsvToType( [string]$TypeName ) {
  $_.PSObject.Properties |
    foreach { $h = @{} } {
      $h[$_.Name] = $_.Value
    } { New-Object $TypeName -Property $h }
}

Import-Csv .\materialList.csv | Convert-CsvToType Material
```