# Value for switch parameter from pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I need to pass parameters to a script from pipeline input by importing the required values from CSV file. The original script has more than 15 parameters to be passed and input values are stored in a CSV file. I am posting a simple example to express the issue.

**Below are the contents of CSV file (`Input.csv`)**

```
ResourceGroupName,SetThrottling
TestRG1,1
TestRG2,0
TestRG3,1
TestRG4,0
TestRG5,0
```

**Script file - `Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1`**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
  [String]$ResourceGroupName,

  [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
  [Switch]$SetThrottling
)

Begin {}
Process {
  Function TestingValues {
    Param(
      $ResourceGroupName,
      $SetThrottling
    )

    Write-Host "$ResourceGroupName is set to $SetThrottling"
  }

  TestingValues -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -SetThrottling $SetThrottling
}
End {}
```

If I run the command `Import-Csv .\Input.csv | .\Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1` it gives an error as given below:

```
C:\Scripts\Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1 : Cannot process argument
transformation on parameter 'SetThrottling'. Cannot convert value
"System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as
$True, $False, 1 or 0.
At line:1 char:26
+ Import-Csv .\Input.csv | .\Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (@{ResourceGroup...etThrottling=1}:PSObject) [Swith-FromPipelineTest.ps1], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1
```

In order to make this work, I have to run below command:

```
Import-Csv -Path .\Input.csv -Verbose |
  Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName,@{n='SetThrottling';e={[bool][int]$_.SetThrottling}} |
  .\Switch-FromPipelineTest.ps1
```

Is there a way we can omit the type casting done by using custom property expression in the second command? As in the original script, I have several `[switch]` parameters and I need to do the same thing for each `[switch]` parameter.

Comment: `[switch][bool][int]$SetThrottling`

Comment: @PetSerAl Is right. The issue is that `Import-CSV` is making all the values strings. You just need to fix the cast.

Comment: Do you mean, this need to be done in Param() block?

Comment: I tested adding this to Param block but still getting error:  
  
`Param
 (
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
 [String]$ResourceGroupName,

 [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
 [switch][bool][int]$SetThrottling
 )
`  
  Now I am getting below error:  
`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SetThrottling'. Cannot convert the "False" value of type 
"System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter" to type "System.Int32".`

Comment: (this won't solve your problem, but it bothers me immensely) - declare your `TestingValues` function in the `Begin` block, rather than in the `Process` block. Absolutely no need for PowerShell to parse and re-define the same function for each input object

Comment: I agree with you Mathias :-). Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, but definitely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857385/quick-way-to-convert-csv-types-to-original-types-with-powershells-import-csv-cm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the string values to boolean values upon importing the CSV:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' |
    Select-Object -Property *,@{n='SetThrottling';e={
        [bool][int]$_.SetThrottling
    }} -Exclude SetThrottling | ...
```

You need to do this for every switch parameter you want to import from a CSV.

If you want to avoid this, change your parameters from switches to set-validated parameters and adjust the parameter evaluation accordingly:

```
[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[ValidateSet('0', '1')]
[string]$SetThrottling
```

Comment: That seems the only option I have (like Ctrl+Alt+Del :-)). I will do this. Thanks.